# MS SQL: is it possible to solve this task in SQL without T/PL sql?

Tags: sql

I was trying a task "calculate minimum number of rooms required to host all the meetings". Result should be "4".

Table meetings is like this:

[image: table].

I was trying with inner join on m2.end > m1.start and m2.start < m1.end and m1.id<>m2.id to get collisions of meetings, in other case I tried with oposite conditions showing meetings that do not collide.

Now im trying to find condition for placing meetings in rooms but im stuck. Any hints or solutions? Table insert was like this, start and end were varchars so they needed casting as time:

```
insert into meetings(id, start1, end1)  
values  
(1, '08:00', '09:00'),  
(3, '11:00', '14:15'),  
(4, '14:15', '16:00'),  
(5, '14:00', '17:00'),  
(6, '10:00', '16:00')
```

To visualize the solution it can be like this: [solution_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6pxv.png) - 4 rooms needed

Comment: why should the result be 4? can you explain and also it would help to see the sql/tables

Comment: I guess what you should do is find difference of starttime and end time order by descending count and use case for the data of count within if other starttime endtime matches

Comment: This is a "bin packing problem".

Comment: the result is 4 because result was given and it is only solution as in "solution_pic" - picture in link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the time when the maximum number of meetings are occuring.

You can do this with a cumulative sum:

```
with m as (
      select m.start as dt, 1 as inc
      from meetings
      union all
      select m.end as dte, -1
      from meetings
     )
select sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dt) as concurrent
from m
group by dt
order by concurrent_desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

The CTE tags when meetings start and end.  The outer query does a cumulative sum and returns the highest value.

Comment: This is the solution, thank you. Its universal and approach is very clear. How did you come to this? Was it visualization on paper and analysis or other way. I was stuck with typical approaches of joins and <> conditions, but did not get close to one like this - well analyzed and smart. Have a good day!

Comment: @johnny_john . . . I'm pretty sure I used this approach decades ago when I was introduced to parallel computing, before I learned SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you had two rows `m1` and `m2`, there would be a scheduling conflict if:

```
(m1.start <= m2.start and m1.end > m2.start) or (m1.start < m2.end and m1.end >= m2.end)
```

Now if you were to join every row in the `meetings` table with itself (however you do not want to compare a row with itself since that would produce a false conflict), you would be testing each pair of rows for scheduling conflicts. But you would be also producing some duplicate conflicts which can be eliminated by selecting distinct room id's. But one problem remains. If you have two rows with identical start and end times, then the above condition will result in two rows returned from the join with distinct keys. So we need to test for the special case of identical time slots and then select arbitrarily one of the rows:

```
select count(distinct m1.id) as cnt
from meetings m1 join meetings m2 on m1.id <> m2.id
where
if(m1.start = m2.start and m1.end = m2.end,
   m1.id < m2.id,
   (m1.start <= m2.start and m1.end > m2.start) or (m1.start < m2.end and m1.end >= m2.end)
   )
;
```

[See db-fiddle #1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fktbvmatb9FCdVAPmoXuts/3)

[See db-fiddle #2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7FdZAbQ9d5tcppBTsYK6zD/2)

Answer (score 0):

> I was trying with inner join on m2.end > m1.start and m2.start <
>   m1.end and m1.id<>m2.id to get collisions of meetings, in other case I
>   tried with oposite conditions showing meetings that do not collide.

Had you used left join, your query would have returned the results you wanted. This is because you would want the query to return at least one record,data for non-overlapping conditions.

Eg:

```
select max(cnt) from (
   select count(*) as cnt
     from meetings m1
left join meetings m2 
       on m1.id <> m2.id and m1.mstart < m2.mend and m1.mend > m2.mstart
  group by m1.id
   )y
```

dbfiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e97802aa55f31833baf9d1a2ec1e8f26

Comment: Hi, thank you for comment, this query shows number of collisions per room and takes maximum of that  "4", it is coincidence that minimum number of rooms to host meetings is the same "4"

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example where this query will not work

Comment: It will not work when 3 meetings take place one after another (so they need 1 room) but 4th meeting starts at begining of 1st meeting and ends at end of 3rd meeting (it needs 1 room itself). Number of collisions for 4th meeting is 3 but 2 rooms are needed in total

Answer (score 0):

*WARNING* : This answer is not intended as a solution. It's more like a little experiment.

For some reason the following 2 calculations somehow calculate the same.

It basically intends to add the total of time ranges that can't be re-used, to those that can.

But I seriously doubt that this method would hold up against the more complicated schedules.
So please choose another solution than this one!

**Sample data:**

> ```
> create table meetings
> (
>   id int primary key,
>   start1 time,
>   end1 time
> );
> insert into meetings(id, start1, end1)  
> values  
> (1, '08:00', '09:00'),  
> (3, '11:00', '14:15'),  
> (4, '14:15', '16:00'),  
> (5, '14:00', '17:00'),  
> (6, '10:00', '16:00')
> ```

**Query 1: Looking to the right**

> ```
> select 
> (
>    count(case when m2.id is null then m1.id end)
>  + count(distinct m1.id) - count(distinct m2.id)
> ) as minimum_rooms
> from meetings m1
> left join meetings m2 
>   on (m2.start1 >= m1.end1)
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | minimum_rooms |
> | ------------: |
> |             4 |
> ```

**Query 2: Looking to the left**

> ```
> select 
> (
>    count(case when m2.id is null then m1.id end)
>  + count(distinct m1.id) - count(distinct m2.id)
> ) as minimum_rooms
> from meetings m1
> left join meetings m2
>   on (m2.end1 <= m1.start1)
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | minimum_rooms |
> | ------------: |
> |             4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bbb9d48cd9095a74f790ed890f41910e)*